# How to get ELMAH to log to Mongodb?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, elmah

i want to use Elmah to log errors into my mongodb database

i am using Asp.net mvc website

i have done following steps already

1.installed Elmah from nuget solution

2. and it successfully log erros in Elmah.axd page

   [image: here is Elmah.axd file]

   now all i want is to log this errors in my mongodb database

   can some one suggest me steps for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [elmah-mongodb](https://github.com/CaptainCodeman/elmah-mongodb) package. Install the `elmah.mongodb` NuGet package and add the following to your `web.confing` file:

```
<elmah>
  <errorLog type="Elmah.MongoErrorLog, Elmah.MongoDB" connectionStringName="elmah-mongodb" maxSize="10485760" maxDocuments="10000"/>
</elmah>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="elmah-mongodb" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/elmah?w=0"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: it will automatically insert record in my database?

Comment: That's the purpose of that package, yes. I know that it haven't been updated recently, why you may experience issues with the mongodb client. But try it out and let me know how it goes :)

Comment: when i add this connectionstring in webconfig it is through me mongodb.bson assembly can not load error

Comment: Did you install the elmah-mongodb package?

Comment: yes when i install elmah-mongodb it is also give me error of other mongodb drivers